# Weight paint not showing

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I having problems to see weight effect area in the viewport.

For example this file:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51093542/35-minecraft-char.blend (right-click and 'Save As' to download .blend file)

used in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkT92aoMpP0

Compare how its shown in the video (around 5:23) and this
[image: weight painting on my model]

In another test if I pose the object and try to weight paint on it:
[image: weight painting on a test model]

So obviously the weights are being applied to the object, I just can't see it like its supposed to do.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The file you sent seems to work fine for me (Running Blender version 2.75a): [image]

Make sure "Custom Weight Paint Range" in the User Preferences under System is unticked:
 [image]

Comment: Is disabled for me too, and the worst part is, if I try to create a new paint range it also doesn't show correctly. Maybe theres something with my graphics card?

Comment: This process should not have anything to do with the graphics card ... I believe.

Answer (score 1):

It was actually a bug, it works on version 2.72, but not in newer versions, is something related to my setup I think (OS or drivers), reporting to developers.
Until then I'll have to use the old version I guess.

Comment: Can you see the weights as normal in a new file?

Comment: @PGmath, no I can't, the error is not in the file, it's just a example at hand, I tested in other files as well.

Comment: You may want to [report the bug](https://developer.blender.org/).

Comment: I reported, is there, but I can see that this are not high priority, may take a while.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the vertex groups show up in weight paint mode, then it could be an error in the settings or just a program issue (if you don't have the latest version, update).

For a simple model like this, one workaround is to set the vertex group weights manually.  For instance, go into edit mode, select all and remove it from the head vertex group, then select only the head geometry (you can hit `L` over it to select connected), and hit assign.  For those half-way rings at the elbows and knees, you'll have to set the weight to 0.500 before assigning.

Read here if this doesn't make any sense: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/vertex_groups.html